# Nested resources with pk's of two different instances

Tags: python, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm doing a Rest API where you can upload photos and add comments/likes to them, like Instagram for example.
I have 3 different models: photos, likes, and comments.

How can I access the nested resources like this:

```
photos/slug_name/comments/pk
```

I already have `photos/` and `photos/slug_name`, and also can achieve the `photos/slug_name/comments` for the creation and list of the comments (Using `@action` in the Photos viewset.) But cant find a way of doing it with the 2 levels of detail (`slug_name` and then `pk`), and that's needed for using PATCH, DELETE and GET over the specific comments.

Comment: Have a look at [`drf-nested-routers`](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers)